# Duda múltiples case when SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sybase

Construí la siguiente consulta con cases anidados que lo único que hace es verificar que insertar en un campo según las condiciones que se cumplan:

```
        I_TIMPTRAS  =   case when convert(decimal(18,2), Fac_Iva) >= @Mon_Centa then
                            case Cre_Tipo   when @Tip_CreSim then
                                                case Cli_Tipo   when @Tip_PerMor then @Str_Vacio
                                                                else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                                                end
                                            else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,2), round(Fac_Iva,2))))
                            end
                        else case Cre_Tipo
                                 when @Tip_CreSim then 
                                    case Cre_CobIVA when @Cob_NoIVA then @Str_Vacio
                                         else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,6), @Mon_Cero)))
                                    end
                                when @Tip_Varios  then
                                    case Cre_CobIVA when @Cob_NoIVA then @Str_Vacio
                                         else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,6), @Mon_Cero)))
                                    end
                                when @Tip_Autos   then
                                    case Cre_CobIVA when @Cob_NoIVA then @Str_Vacio
                                         else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,6), @Mon_Cero)))
                                    end     
                                end                 
                        else convert(char(10),(convert(decimal(18,6), @Mon_Cero)))
                        end,
```

Mi duda surge en el `else case Cre_Tipo` donde checa dependiendo de lo que haya en ese campo va a registrar algo en especifico, pero me marca error de sintaxis cerca de ese else, cabe mencionar que inserta lo mismo en cada uno, solo depende de que tenga en el campo `Cre_Tipo`

Todo esto es mediante Sybase ASE, espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!